# It is possible to add TabBarController to a subview?

Tags: iphone

I am developing a new application. In my application it required firstly signing and registration page. After that it will show tab bar controller. So is it possible to add tabBarController in thirdView without using presentModelViewController?

Answer (score 0):

You normally create your `UITabBarController`, fill in the desired `viewcontrollers`

for example you have a `UITabBarController` called `tabBar`

you can add `tabBar.view` to any `UIView`

```
[self.view addSubView:tabBar.view];
```

Comment: its not working.. i am using view base application and add a button. then call the touch up inside method in this button and call a next view. in this view add a tabbar controller. drag and drop it..

Comment: please sir give me one help. its a big problem for me.

Comment: if this problem is solved. its a big problem solving in my application. and i am thankful to you..

Comment: my email is buntydada2@gmail.com